# Test if all elements of a list are different from each other

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have a list of lists and want to test if all elements are different from each other, i.e. equal should return nil for all combinations of list elements.

E.g.

```
(defparameter feld '((1 0 0 5 5 0) 
                     (0 0 0 0 0 0) 
                     (1 1 5 5 0 0) 
                     (0 1 0 1 5 5) 
                     (5 5 1 0 1 0) 
                     (1 0 1 0 5 5)))
```

I thought of using reduce but as far as I understand it only tests the equality of neighbors, as would do a loop construct like:

```
(loop for i below (length feld) 
      for j from 1 
          if (equal (nth i feld) (nth j feld)) return t)
```

Is there a simple way using a standard construct which I do not see at the moment or do I have to create a recursive function?

The whole data structure represents a "board game" where every list is a line on the board and each element in the inside-lists is a value of this very field. The three numerical values (0, 1 and 5) are something like empty, Symbol A and Symbol B. A valid board cannot have two identical lines. This is why I want to identify those.

Basically, it is like remove-duplicates without removing. In the meantime I was thinking about something like this:

```
(defun duplicates-p (lst)
  (cond ((null lst) '())
        ((member (car lst) (cdr lst)) t)
        (t (duplicates-p (rest lst)))))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
(defun unique (lsts &aux (h (make-hash-table :test 'equal)))
  (loop :for lst :in lsts
        :never (gethash lst h)
        :do (setf (gethash lst h) t)))
```

Comment: I find the `finally` clause here superfluous and confusing.

Comment: While it is not required by the given question, a more general function would test the second return value of `gethash` instead of the first, so that empty lists could also not appear twice.

Comment: @svante two empty lists will evaluate correctly to `nil` since the value for each present keys are `t`. Indeed the `finally` wasn't needed. I didn't think about removing it when i replaced `if` with `never`.

Comment: You're right, I didn't read that correctly.  My instinct would be to save the item itself in the hash-table and test for presence, not the value.  That could also help in modifying this to show _which_ value was the "offender" in an error message.